# What roles do these phrases take?

Tags: complementation, modifiers, metaphors

> LABOR UNITY HAS BEEN SHORT LIVED. GRUMBLING HAS now BROKEN OUT WITHIN
>   OPPOSITION RANKS OVER THE ROLE PLAYED BY FACTIONS IN CHOOSING THE
>   FRONTBENCH.  [(ABC)](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-10-15/news-in-90-seconds/5022468)

It seems like ‘*over the role*’ is the complement of ‘*grumbling*’. But I’m not sure what ‘*played by faction*’ and ‘*in choosing the frontbench*’ are respectively modifying or what role do they take in the sentence. Would you parse them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Played...* modifies *role*: the factions played a role.

*In choosing...* is ambiguous, because ***play a role in*** is semantically a unitary but very complex metaphor:

> > The factions play a role in choosing the frontbench.
> >     Olivier plays the Prince in *Hamlet*.

- The factions are represented as an 'actor portraying a character' (playing a role) in a 'drama', so *in choosing...* is a prepositional phrase modifying both the factions and the role.
- But the role was played 'in the drama', so *in choosing* also modifies *played*.
- Yet the action performed by both the actors and the character was *choosing...*, so both the factions and the role are the subject of the clause *choosing...* .
- Finally, the object of *over*—what the grumbling was about—is not *the role* but the entire NP headed by *the role*; and what that NP signifies is the manner in which the drama was performed: *how the frontbench was chosen*.

The theatrical metaphor is notoriously hard to pin down. Kenneth Burke chose it as the generative core of his study of human relationships, *A Grammar of Motives*, because "what we want is *not terms that avoid ambiguity*, but *terms that clearly reveal the strategic spots at which ambiguities necessarily arise.*"